# Eloquent using parent field in subquery

Tags: eloquent, subquery, lumen

How can i access the 'id' field in the first query, and use it in the second subquery in this example:

```
   $users = \App\User::where('active', 1)->where('deleted_at', null)->where('recieve_jobagent', 1)
        ->with(['companies' => function($query){

            $query->where('active', 1);

            $query->with(['posts' => function($posts){

                $posts->where('active', 1);

                $posts->whereHas('users', function($postUsers){


                    **I do not have access to 'users.id' here**
                    $postUsers->where('user_id', 'users.id');

                });

            }]);

        }]);
```

I'm using lumen 5.1.

My goal here is to get all users and their related companies, and the companies' posts that isn't related to the user.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you need to do that.  You can use `whereHas` and by drilling down into the relationships it returns only the ones that belong to the thing you're querying.

Without seeing your relationship structure, I would assume you need something like this?

```
$users = \App\User::where('active', 1)->where('deleted_at', null)->where('recieve_jobagent', 1)
    ->whereHas('companies', function($query){
        $query->where('active', 1)
        ->whereHas('posts', function($query){
            where('active', 1);
        })
    })
    ->with(['companies' => function($query){
        $query->where('active', 1);
        $query->with(['posts' => function($posts){
            $posts->where('active', 1);
        }]);
    }]);
```

Comment: This looks great! I added the bounty because I have a similar problem. The model is as follows: Class -> Trainers. I want all classes where one of the trainers is X, then return the class with all of its trainers. Looks like `whereHas` will do the trick. Right?

Comment: You probably want to open your own question @jessehouwing but you sounds like you would need to use `whereHas` with your query criteria and then `with` to lazy load all trainers.

Comment: encounter a similar problem, but it is really helpful ans!